# compass with eclipselink

Tags: eclipselink, compass-lucene

I am trying to setup compass with eclipselink. It throws me the following exception

> Exception [EclipseLink-28014] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>       Exception Description: Exception was thrown while processing property [eclipselink.session.customizer] with value [org.compass.gps.device.jpa.embedded.eclipselink.CompassSessionCustomizer].
>       Internal Exception: org.compass.core.CompassException: Failed to find Persistence Unit Info
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.failedWhileProcessingProperty(EntityManagerSetupException.java:178)

My persistence.xml is as follows:

```
<property name="eclipselink.session.customizer"                      value="org.compass.gps.device.jpa.embedded.eclipselink.CompassSessionCustomizer"/>
<property name="compass.engine.connection" value="target/test-index"/>
<property name="compass.debug" value="true" />
```

I have copied the following jar to my WEB-INF/lib

- compass-2.2.0
- lucene-core
- lucene-analyzers
- lucene-spellchecker
- lucene-snowball
- lucene-queries
- lucene-highlighter

Am i missing anything ?

Thanks.

Comment: compass is not actively being maintained for the past year or so. ElasticSearch is the new project started by the compass owner and if you are starting now then i'd suggest you either look at Hibernate Search or EalsticSearch

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I just had a quick look at elastic search and could not find out how can I use it with eclipselink.. may be I have to dig further.. will look at hibernate search as well..

Comment: Hi, I found the problem. property name eclipselink.session.customizer was wrong. it has start with "compass.". Anyway, please let me know if there are any good documentations on how to integrate eclipselink with Hibernate Search or EalsticSearch.

Comment: did you ever find any good documentation on using EclipseLink with Compass?